# How to get input from multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm just starting to play around with JavaScript and Jquery and have hit a roadblock. I want users to be able to add & subtract boxes and fill it with input. Here's my html

```
<body>

<h1>Math Grades</h1>
<div id="mathGrades">
  <input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:16pt; text-align: center" type='number' id="fooBar">
  <input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:16pt; text-align: center" type='number' id="fooBar">
</div>

<button type="button" id="addBox">+</button>
<button type="button" id="subtractBox">-</button>

<br>
<button type="button" id="getGrades">Submit Grades</button>

<script src="calcjq.js"></script>
```

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var addMathBox = document.getElementById("addBox");
addMathBox.addEventListener('click', addBox, false);

var subtractMathBox = document.getElementById("subtractBox");
subtractMathBox.addEventListener('click', subtractBox, false);

var getScores = document.getElementById("getGrades");
getScores.addEventListener('click', getUserGrades, false);

function getUserGrades(){
    var userGrades = document.getElementById("fooBar").value;
    console.log(userGrades);
}

function subtractBox(){
    $('#fooBar').remove()
}

function addBox(){
    $('#mathGrades').append('<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:16pt; text-align: center" type="number" id="fooBar">')
};


});
```

How can I make sure to gather all of the input without knowing how many boxes they'll add and fill?

EDIT

Finally found a way to do this:

```
var mathGrades = $("input[class='mathGrades']")
            .map(function(){return parseInt($(this).val(), 10);}).get();
```

Comment: You could set a class name for the new input and use a for loop. **(ID's should be unique)** I don't recommend duplicating the same ID, javascript will only read the first element with that ID.

Comment: id's must be unique. try giving them a common name or a class and use the name selector or the class selector in jquery to refer those textboxes. you can do `$('input[name="someName"]').each(function(){ // your code});` if you're using name or u can use `$('.className').each(function(){// ur code});` where '`.className`' is the class applied to ur inputs

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and you probably know this but I wanted to point it out any way, your id attribute should be unique for each element. So make sure it's not foobar for all of them.

What you could do to solve your problem is add a unique class, i.e. mathGrades, to each input and then use the following code to collect all of the data and do as you please with it.

```
var mathGrades = document.getElementsByClassName('mathGrades');
var m, v;
for(m in mathGrades) {
    v = $(mathGrades[m]).val(); // takes value and converts to string i.e. "1"
    $(mathGrades[m]).val(v+1); // assigns new value "1" + "1" = "11"
}
```

In your javascript you could change the function addBox to:

```
function addBox() {
    $('#mathGrades').append('<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:16pt; text-align: center" type="number" class="mathGrades">')
};
```

Comment: Me not knowing enough, I was thinking that if the ids were the same, I'd be able to pull all of the info from them....lesson learned!

Comment: That code actually doesn't work. When I tried it, I got this error message `mathGrades[m].val is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: `function getUserGrades() { var userGrades = document.getElementsByClassName("mathGrades"); console.log(userGrades.length); /* for debugging to see if userGrades isn't empty */ var m; for(m=0; m < userGrades.length; m++) userGrades[m].attr('value') += 1; }`

I wrote this function in context with the `getUserGrades()` method you wrote above.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something (I used your code exactly), but it returned `Uncaught TypeError: userGrades[m].attr is not a function` and I'm not sure why. It did log the correct length, but then I get hit with the error message. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Try `$(mathGrades[m]).val();` instead.

Comment: This is much more difficult than I thought haha. It's now returning this error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`...we just keep hitting roadblock after roadblock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83904/discussion-between-himanish-k-and-nick).

Comment: It's not a problem. It's giving the above error because of the way we are using it. We are basically setting the value of each box in this, for which we should be using `var v = $(mathGrades[m]).val(); /* getter */ $(mathGrades[m]).val(v); /* setter */`. But it gives error when `toLowerCase()` is called somewhere in jquery code.